# Python - Using the django that is installed in the virtualenv

Tags: python, django, file, static, virtualenv

I've installed Django 1.8 in the virtualenv and I'm trying to use the static files from it.
For Example, if I want to edit the header color of the admin base.html, It keeps using the django global file (1.7) even though I'm working with my virtualenv on.

Doesn't my **STATIC_URL = '/static/'** use the django that is currently running in my virtualenv?

Sorry for the bad English

Comment: Your question is confusing. Static files are served by your webserver, so you need to point that to the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

> virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.

It doesn't have anything to do with your code and static_url settings, only thing different is what packages you have there and what django core version you are using.